# how to put contents of 2 integer array into 1 single arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I tried below code,
It works only for 1 array, when i try to add another, it throws an runtime exception

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
   at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
    at general.ArrToArrList.main(ArrToArrList.java:32)
```

The code is

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrToArrList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] nums = new Integer[5];
        nums[0] = 2;
        nums[1] = 4;
        Integer[] nm = { 3, 5, 7 };
        List intList = (Arrays.asList(nums));
        List intList2 = (Arrays.asList(nm));
        intList.addAll(Arrays.asList(nm));
        for (Integer i : intList) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make sure to format your code correctly. There's a live preview at the bottom of the input box.

Comment: import java.util.Arrays;  
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;  
import java.util.ArrayList;  
public class ArrToArrList 
{  
   public static void main(String[] args)  
   {  
    
      Integer[] nums = new Integer[5];  
      nums[0]=2;
      nums[1]=4;
    Integer[] nm ={3,5,7};
      List<Integer> intList = (Arrays.asList(nums));
      List<Integer> intList2 = (Arrays.asList(nm));
      intList.addAll(Arrays.asList(nm));
      

      for (Integer i :intList)
      {
       
          System.out.println(i);
      }
   }  
}

Comment: @sweety123 From next time on words please format your code and post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [the actual contract for `Arrays#asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29). It produces a `List` that is just a wrapper around the existing array and doesn't support any operations that would resize the array.

If you are wanting to combine the arrays, you need to create a new `List` object that is resizeable. Try

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(nums));
intList.addAll(Arrays.asList(nm));
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Arrays.asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) returns a fixed sized `List`. i.e. no elements can be added or removed. Wrap the result of `asList` in a new `ArrayList` to allow elements to be added

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(nums));
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays.asList wraps an array to appear as a List.  An array cannot be grown, or shrunk and so you cannot add or remove elements from this list.

Perhaps what you intended was

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(nums));
```

Answer (score 2):

`List`s created using `Arrays.asList` have a fixed size and thus you can't add other elements to the list. You could create a new normal `ArrayList` and add all elements to the list, like this:

```
Integer[] nums = new Integer[5];
nums[0] = 2;
nums[1] = 4;
Integer[] nm = { 3, 5, 7 };
List intList = (Arrays.asList(nums));
List intList2 = (Arrays.asList(nm));
List mergeList = new ArrayList();
mergeList .addAll(Arrays.asList(nums));
mergeList .addAll(Arrays.asList(nm));
for (Integer i : mergeList) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you use

```
List intList = (Arrays.asList(nums));
```

it gives the actual object of type java.util.Arrays$ArrayList which has the implementation as

```
public void add(int index, E element) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

but if you use

```
List intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(nums);
```

it will give you a actual object of type java.util.ArrayList . This makes the difference . This is actually the reason to the cause of this Exception

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.asList` returns an fixed size view of the underlying array:

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.<sup>[1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)</sup>

You cannot put more elements into the returned `List` than there were in the array.

You need to copy that into a `java.util.ArrayList` (confusingly `Arrays.asList` returns a `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` which is not the same thing.)

```
final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(myArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

The list you get from Arrays.asList isn't mutable.  So you need to assign it to intList using the new operator.